# How to use tf.gather if the index is probabilistic form in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to use probability to choose the array.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
T = np.array([[0.6, 0.1, 0.3], [0.2,0.7,0.1], [0.1,0.1,0.8]])
labels = np.array([1,2,0])
preds = np.array([[0.2,0.7,0.1]])
```

In `tf.gather`, if index is integer, it can work.

```
K.get_value(tf.gather(T, labels))

array([[0.2, 0.7, 0.1],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.8],
       [0.6, 0.1, 0.3]])
```

However, now my index is probabilistic form, I hope it can still work like this:

```
K.get_value(tf.gather(T, preds))
```

Here, I want to select the index `0` with a probability of `0.2`, select the index `1` with a probability of `0.7`, and select the index `2` with a probability of `0.1`.

`Expected result:`

```
0.2*[0.6, 0.1, 0.3] + 0.7*[0.2,0.7,0.1] + 0.1*[0.1,0.1,0.8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a type of weighted sum so the good news is that you don't need to use `tf.gather`. In general, you need the following.

Given `T` `(n, t_cols)`  and `preds` `(p_rows, n)`, you need, `(p_rows, t_cols)` sized output. Where each row in the output is a weighted sum of rows of `T`.

Here's what you can do. This involves understanding [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules.

We are doing the following.

- Make T of shape [t_cols, n, 1]
- Make preds of shape [n, p_rows]
- Multiply the two, which gives `[t_cols, n, p_rows]`
- Reduce sum on n, which gives `[t_cols, p_rows]`
- Transpose, which gives `[p_rows, t_cols]`

```
T = tf.constant(np.array([[0.6, 0.1, 0.3], [0.2,0.7,0.1], [0.1,0.1,0.8]]))
preds = tf.constant(np.array([[0.2,0.7,0.1],[0.2,0.4,0.4]]))

mul = tf.transpose(T)[:,:,tf.newaxis] * tf.transpose(preds)
res = tf.transpose(tf.reduce_sum(mul, axis=1))
```

`res` will have the result you need.